# Automatically dispose of 3D models once out of view

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

In order to save memory in my application I've decided to dispose of any 3D models that escape the view of the camera. To do this I used a method which detects if the camera is able to see the position of the model (using `model.position`). The below code is within my `animate` loop.

```js
const frustum = new THREE.Frustum();
const matrix = new THREE.Matrix4().multiplyMatrices(test.camera.projectionMatrix, test.camera.matrixWorldInverse);
frustum.setFromProjectionMatrix(matrix);

let earthContainerPos = { ...earthContainer.position }; //spread syntax removes reference to container position
earthContainerPos.z += 10; //to ensure its only disposed once completely out of view (since .position is the center of the model)
if (!frustum.containsPoint(earthContainerPos)) { //check if container in view of camera
   console.log('Out of view')
   earthContainer.dispose(); //dispose of the model - I thought .dispose would work since its being rendered by a webGL renderer (from the docs) but it didnt
};
```

The method works for detecting when my model is out of view, but for some reason the dispose  method for my container (which holds 2 3D Models) is not working. Do I have to dispose of everything or is there a more dynamic method of disposal?

---

**Model Details:**

- GLTF models
- 2 models in the container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> earthContainer.dispose();

If `earthContainer` is an instance of `Object3D`, your code will produce a runtime error. `dispose()` methods only exist for selected classes like `BufferGeometry`, `Material`, `Texture` or `WebGLRenderTarget`.

Besides, I don't think your approach of calling `dispose()` when an 3D objects gets out of view makes sense. The engine automatically ensures to only render objects when they are inside the view frustum. That is more effective than what you do since it can lead to expensive ping-pong effects. Meaning you deallocate resources which could be allocated again in the next frames. And this back-and-forth can produce noticeably overhead. E.g. if you call `dispose()` on a material, its respective shader might be deleted. If you know have to render an object with this material again, a new compilation is required which is an expensive operation.

I suggest you only call `dispose()` if your application does not require a resource again. More information about `dispose()` in the following guide:

https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/How-to-dispose-of-objects

Comment: I was thinking more on this and surely if you don't dispose the model it takes up memory in just caching it? Does the renderer dynamically load and re-load the models once out of view?

Comment: The renderer will keep the objects in memory.

Comment: So, how would I remove them from memory? I would like to do this because I know I will not use the models again so they’re just taking up memory.

Comment: In this case, remove the 3D objects from the scene and make sure that your app holds no references to them. You can then use `dispose()` on resources like materials or texture that you definitely don't need anymore.